# Dash to Panel extension won't show Settings

Tags: gnome, 21.10

I've installed the GNOME Dash to Panel extension on my fresh install of Ubuntu 21.10, but when I try to open the Settings of the extension it shows briefly in the panel then fades away before the Settings window appears.  Has anyone else seen this behavior and, perhaps more importantly, found a fix?  I get the same result if I right-click on the panel and select "Dash to Panel Settings" as when I click on the Configure button in Installed Extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Extensions can break between versions of Gnome Shell. A more foolproof way to install Gnome Shell extensions is using the Software Store. These extensions are packed to work with your specific Ubuntu version.

The selection there is limited, but "Dash to Panel" is featured and can be installed. If you prefer the terminal, install it with

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-dash-to-panel
```

Enable the extension in your account using the "Extensions" tool. It is not installed by default. It is available as the package `gnome-shell-extension-prefs`. This version of the extension will likely work better.

Comment: Following your instructions, I installed both gnome-shell-extension-prefs and gnome-shell-extension-dash-to-panel from the command line.  Using the Extensions tool, I still can't enable Dash to Panel; I get a file not found error.  Nor can I find it when I list the extensions.  I think you've steered me in the right direction, but I'm obviously doing something wrong.

Comment: Difficult indeed for me to see from here what you might be missing.